# kafka-node consumer-group not consuming message from all partitions

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

So, I am trying to listen to a kafka client which has 3 partitions, and topic named = "some_test_topic";

I have written below code to consume the messages from the latest offset.

```
var async = require('async');
var ConsumerGroup = require('kafka-node').ConsumerGroup;
var logger = winston.logstart();

var buildConsumerOptions = {
    host: 'example.com:2181',
    autoCommit: false,
    groupId: 'some_test_topic',
    sessionTimeout: 15000,
    protocol: ['roundrobin'],
    partitioner: 3, // Not sure if kafka-node is using this or not.
    fromOffset: 'earliest' // other options 'none', 'earliest'
};
var buildTopics = ['build_status_events'];
var consumerGroup = new ConsumerGroup(Object.assign({id: 'build_status_events'}, buildConsumerOptions), buildTopics);
var consumerGroup1 = new ConsumerGroup(Object.assign({id: 'build_status_events'}, buildConsumerOptions), buildTopics);
module.exports = {
    listenBuildEventsKafka: function(connections){
        try{
            // var consumerGroup = new ConsumerGroup(Object.assign({id: 'build_status_events'}, buildConsumerOptions), buildTopics);
            consumerGroup.on('error', onError);
            consumerGroup.on('message', onMessage);
            consumerGroup1.on('error', onError);
            consumerGroup1.on('message', onMessage);
            consumerGroup.on('connect', function(){
                logger.info("ConsumerGroup is ready. ");
            });
            consumerGroup1.on('connect', function(){
                logger.info("ConsumerGroup1 is ready. ");
            });
            function onMessage(message){
                var jsonData = JSON.parse(message.value);
                console.log(" -- " +jsonData.buildid+ " Time: " +jsonData.time + " Offset: " +message.offset+ " Partition: " +message.partition);
            }
            function onError (error) {
              logger.error("Some error occured while listening kafka events " +error);
            }
            process.once('SIGINT', function(){
                async.each([consumerGroup, consumerGroup1], function (consumer, callback) {
                    logger.info("Closing the kafka build consumer process");
                    consumer.close(true, callback);
                });
            })
        }catch(error){
            logger.error("Could not connect to kafka events for build " +error);
        }
    }
};
```

Somehow when I run this code, it just consumes events from partition 0  and partition 1. None of the events from partition2 is printed.

Not sure, what else I need to configure here. I tried doing enough google but could not find anything useful.
Also, I tried adding partitionerType= 1 to 4 (one by one).. but nothing helped. 
Can anyone please help me here.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you able to resolve this issue?